# handling parameters and return values between custom schema methods written in diffrent languages

Tags: structr

first, what I'd like to achieve is the following:

I need to pass an image from an external source into the underlying database of structr. therefore I need to convert that image to base64. But as I'm not aware of a way to get serverside javascript/rhino to receive an image via url and convert it into base64, I came up with a workaround:

so I wrote two schema methods, one (script A) in serverside javascript and the other (script B) in php.

script A kind of imports data from an external REST API, builds the external image url and needs to pass it to script B which will use cURL to get the image, convert it to base64 and hand it back to script A.

So that's where I'm stuck right now. [Help Article on Custom Schema Methods](https://support.structr.com/article/321) doesn't really help, because neither covers it PHP syntax nor does it state if it's even possible to return something from a custom schema method.

[evaluate_script()](https://support.structr.com/article/510) or [replace()](https://support.structr.com/article/26) are other possibilities, but I'm still not sure how to use it within the given context.

Maybe there's another way handling that issue, I'm open for suggestions.

```
SCRIPT A: Serverside Javascript Method:
var url = 'image_url",
instance = Structr.get('this'),
base64String = Instance.PHPMethod(url); 
//then write base64String to structr database

SCRIPT B: PHP Method:
php{
<?php 
$url = retrieve.url from SCRIPT A ????;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
$b64 = base64_encode($data); 
echo $b64;
?>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** For structr 3.5+ the newer answer from @Axel Morgner is better. If you are using a version >= 3.5, rather use that code than this.

---

I'll assume your PHP Script is a global schema method and is called `getImageAsBase64PHP`. Then the solution would work like this:

```
php{
    <?php 
        $url = $Structr->get('imageUrl');

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl); 
        $b64 = base64_encode($data);

        $Structr->call('store', 'downloadedImageBaseData', $b64);
    ?>
}
```

This method could be called like so:

```
{
    // call the global schema method (this is admin-only! if this needs to be initiated by a regular user, use doPrivileged())
    // the parameter "imageUrl" will be used in the PHP script
    $.call('getImageAsBase64PHP', {
        imageUrl: 'https://structr.com/new/content-img/screenshots/screenshot-schema-blog.png'
    });

    // the base64 encoded string provided by the other method
    let baseData = $.retrieve('downloadedImageBaseData');

    // create a new file with name "test.png" and the base64Data string as content
    $.create('Image', 'name', 'test.png', 'base64Data', baseData.toString());
}
```

In the current version this is the best I can do as this is a use-case we had not yet encountered. In one of the next versions there will be a way easier method to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

With the two commits
https://github.com/structr/structr/commit/0390805c834d50fe4b6d8c7b3d86e90242e8df77
and
https://github.com/structr/structr/commit/88e8cb6cd24bfca33ecc674f60d625108cb8eec8 (which will both be included in the upcoming release 3.5), we added support for binary data to the HTTP `GET()` function and direct binary processing to `base64encode` but also for `set_content()` and `append_content()` so the image data can directly be written to a file:

Server-side JavaScript:

```
${{
    let data = $.GET('https://some.host.domain/img.png', 'application/octet-stream');
    let img = $.getOrCreate('File', 'name', 'img.png', 'contentType', 'image/png');
    $.setContent(img, data);
}}
```

Or even shorter in StructrScript:

```
${set_content(get_or_create('File', 'name', 'img.png', 'contentType', 'image/png'), GET('https://some.host.domain/img.png', 'application/octet-stream'))}
```